# How to render an image link in Datatable

Tags: javascript, flask, datatable, jinja2

I have the following table in a flask app. The first column is supposed to render a fully formed linked  statement for example:

```
<a href ="https://www.website.com/i=2xyz2g" target="_blank"> <img src="/static/assets/img/abc.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

The data comes from a query:
Table looks thus:

```
 |img                               |  Title   | 
 -----------------------------------------------
 |  the <a> script  above goes here | some text|
```

I would like to write the javascript to render the image/link.

> ```
>                     <table id="table_id" class="display compact" style="width:100%">
>                         <thead>
>                             <tr>
>                                 {% for col in img_list_cols %}
>                                 <th>{{col}}</th>
>                                 {% endfor %}
>                             </tr>
>                         </thead>
>                         <tbody>
>                             {% for row in img_list_rows %}
>                             <tr>
>                                 {% for row_data in row %}
>                                 <td>{{row_data}}</td>
>                                 {% endfor %}
>                             </tr>
>                             {% endfor %}
>                         </tbody>
>                     </table>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jinja [`safe`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#html-escaping) filter, e.g..

```
<td>{{row_data|safe}}</td>
```